# Polymorphism with a final class that implements an associatedtype protocol in swift

Tags: swift, polymorphism

I'm using [Apollo v0.49.0](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-ios/tree/0.49.0). It's a library for calling graphQL endpoints, and the way it does this is by generating code before you compile your code.

Before I talk about the generated code, I'd like to talk about what the generated code implements. For this question, it's the `GraphQLMutation` that's relevant. Here's what it looks like:

```
public enum GraphQLOperationType {
  case query
  case mutation
  case subscription
}

public protocol GraphQLOperation: AnyObject {
  var operationType: GraphQLOperationType { get }

  var operationDefinition: String { get }
  var operationIdentifier: String? { get }
  var operationName: String { get }

  var queryDocument: String { get }

  var variables: GraphQLMap? { get }

  associatedtype Data: GraphQLSelectionSet
}

public extension GraphQLOperation {
  var queryDocument: String {
    return operationDefinition
  }

  var operationIdentifier: String? {
    return nil
  }

  var variables: GraphQLMap? {
    return nil
  }
}

public protocol GraphQLQuery: GraphQLOperation {}
public extension GraphQLQuery {
  var operationType: GraphQLOperationType { return .query }
}

public protocol GraphQLMutation: GraphQLOperation {}
public extension GraphQLMutation {
  var operationType: GraphQLOperationType { return .mutation }
}
```

This is 80% of [the file](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-ios/blob/0.49.0/Sources/Apollo/GraphQLOperation.swift); the last 20% is irrelevant IMHO. Note how `GraphQLMutation` implements `GraphQLOperation` and the latter has an `associatedtype`.

The library generates classes based on your graphql server endpoints. Here's what they look like:

```
public final class ConcreteMutation: GraphQLMutation {
    ...
    public struct Data: GraphQLSelectionSet {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

As far as I know (I'm new to Swift), I have no control over any of the code I've mentioned so far (other than forking the repo and modifying it). I could change them locally, but they would just be overridden every time they were regenerated.

To use any of these generated classes, I have to pass them into this `ApolloClient` function (also a library class):

```
@discardableResult
public func perform<Mutation: GraphQLMutation>(mutation: Mutation,
                                                 publishResultToStore: Bool = true,
                                                 queue: DispatchQueue = .main,
                                                 resultHandler: GraphQLResultHandler<Mutation.Data>? = nil) -> Cancellable {
    return self.networkTransport.send(
      operation: mutation,
      cachePolicy: publishResultToStore ? .default : .fetchIgnoringCacheCompletely,
      contextIdentifier: nil,
      callbackQueue: queue,
      completionHandler: { result in
        resultHandler?(result)
      }
    )
  }
```

I can't figure out how to deal with `ConcreteMutation` in a generic way. I want to be able to write a factory function like so:

```
extension SomeEnum {
   func getMutation<T: GraphQLMutation>() -> T {
        switch self {
            case .a:
                return ConcreteMutation1(first_name: value) as T
            case .b:
                return ConcreteMutation2(last_name: value) as T
            case .c:
                return ConcreteMutation3(bio: value) as T
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

The fact that this func is in an enum is irrelevant to me: that same code could be in a struct/class/whatever. *What matters is the function signature.* I want a factory method that returns a `GraphQLMutation` that can be passed into `ApolloClient.perform()`

Because I can't figure out a way to do either of those things, I end up writing a bunch of functions like this instead:

```
func useConcreteMutation1(value) -> Void {
    let mutation = ConcreteMutation1(first_name: value)
    apolloClient.perform(mutation: mutation)
}

func useConcreteMutation2(value) -> Void {
    let mutation = ConcreteMutation2(last_name: value)
    apolloClient.perform(mutation: mutation)
}

...
```

That's a lot of duplicated code.

Depending on how I fiddle with my `getMutation` signature -- e.g., `<T: GraphQLMutation>() -> T?` etc. -- I can get the func to compile, but I get a different compile error when I try to pass it into `ApolloClient.perform()`. Something saying "protocol can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements."

I've researched this a lot, and my research found [this article](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/how-to-fix-the-error-protocol-can-only-be-used-as-a-generic-constraint-because-it-has-self-or-associated-type-requirements), but I don't think it's an option if the concrete classes implementing the associated type are final?

It's really difficult to figure out if it's possible to use polymorphism in this situation. I can find plenty of articles of what you *can* do, but no articles on what you *can't* do. My question is:

**How do I write `getMutation` so it returns a value that can be passed into `ApolloClient.perform()`?**

Comment: For one of the `ConcreteMutation`, where is the type for `Data` established?  Are they generated with type aliases in them defining `Data`

Comment: @ScottThompson I updated my question. It seems to be a public struct? Am I looking at the wrong thing? Let me know if you want more information about that implementation.

Comment: @DanielKaplan I'm also facing the same issue. Will you please provide your final solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fundamental problem you are running into is that this function signature:

```
func getMutation<T: GraphQLMutation>() -> T
```

is ambiguous.  The reason it's ambiguous is because GraphQLMutation has an associated type (`Data`) and that information doesn't appear anywhere in your function declaration.

When you do this:

```
extension SomeEnum {
   func getMutation<T: GraphQLMutation>() -> T {
        switch self {
            case .a:
                return ConcreteMutation1(first_name: value) as T
            case .b:
                return ConcreteMutation2(last_name: value) as T
            case .c:
                return ConcreteMutation3(bio: value) as T
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Each of those branches could have a different type.  `ConcreteMutation1` could have a `Data` that is `Dormouse` while `ConcreteMutation3` might have a data value that's an `IceCreamTruck`. You may be able to tell the compiler to ignore that but then you run into problems later because `Dormouse` and `IceCreamTruck` are two structs with VERY different sizes and the compiler might need to use different strategies to pass them as parameters.

`Apollo.perform` is also a template. The compiler is going to write a different function based on that template for each type of mutation you call it with. In order to do that *must* know the full type signature of the mutation including what its `Data` associated type is.  Should the `responseHandler` callback be able to handle something the size of a `Dormouse`, or does it need to be able to handle something the size of an `IceCreamTruck`?

If the compiler doesn't know, it can't set up the proper calling sequence for the `responseHandler`.  Bad things would happen if you tried to squeeze something the size of an `IceCreamTruck` through a callback calling sequence that was designed for a parameter the size of a `Dormouse`!

If the compiler doesn't know what type of `Data` the mutation has to offer, it can't write a correct version of `perform` from the template.

If you've only handed it the result of `func getMutation<T: GraphQLMutation>() -> T` where you've eliminated evidence of what the `Data` type is, it doesn't know what version of `perform` it should write.

You are trying to hide the type of `Data`, but you also want the compiler to create a `perform` function where the type of `Data` is known.  You can't do both.

Comment: Interesting. Since I can't do both, is there a solution that's better than my current one: copying and pasting almost the same function over and over again?

Comment: Why do you have the intermediate function `useConcreteMutation2`?  What benefit does it offer you over `apolloClient.perform(mutation: ConcreteMutation2(last_name: value))`?    (I suspect the value would be more obvious if the functions didn't have placeholder names).

Comment: That's a very good question. I'll have to look into that and get back to you, but thank you for the help so far.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to implement `AnyGraphQLMutation` type erased over the `associatedtype`.
There are a bunch of resources online for that matter (type erasure), I've found [this one](https://bignerdranch.com/blog/breaking-down-type-erasure-in-swift/) pretty exhaustive.

Comment: Thank you for the help, but can you show me how I would do it with the code from my example? The main challenge I'm having with this question is getting a yes/no on whether a solution exists.

Comment: I would if you'd made clear something else: what `SomeClass` is and what are you switching over in that method prototype.

Comment: Also your (?) protocol `GraphQLOperation` is the one having the associatedtype (bad naming btw) `Data` which I don't see being used anywhere in its properties. One last thing: what is `GraphQLSelectionSet`?

Comment: Regarding your first question, SomeClass is an enum. I'm switching over the elements of the enum. Regarding your second question, sorry, but that is not my code, it's Apollo's. Here's a link to GraphQLSelectionSet: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-ios/blob/0.49.0/Sources/Apollo/GraphQLSelectionSet.swift

Comment: Feels like type erasing won't help in this case, as you'll lose all the type information that helps `ApolloClient.perform`  to determine what result to pass back into the completion handler.

Comment: No it won’t: that method is generic and takes as parameter a type conforming to GraphQLMutation protocol (a type erased AnyGraphQLMutation concrete type obviously conforms to the protocol). The result to pass to the closure is the erased associated type Data. The problem I see here is that GraphQLMutation protocol was just a bad idea: it inherits from GraphQLOperation only to deliver a default implementation, the whole architecture feels as If protocols were used as if they were classes.

Comment: @Daniel Kaplan So based on the comments we've exchanged, if I got it right, you're basically trying to have an `enum` with associated types, where its cases represent an operation (that'll be your `SomeClass` type). You'll then switch on it, extract the associated value to the case and use the perform method suiting the case. Is that so?

Comment: I don't think so, but I'm not 100% sure. What I want is a *single* `useConcreteMutation` function that I can pass any `GraphQLMutation` into. But I can only figure out how to create a `useConcreteMutation` for *each* `GraphQLMutation`. How I pull this off doesn't matter much to me, so long as I don't have to modify the generated code.

Comment: It's not really clear what are you trying to achieve: `GraphQLMutation` is a protocol that inherits from `GraphQLOperation` only to deliver a default implementation of `operationType`. I don't really see the necessity of that, you could have just made a generic method `perform<O: GraphQLOperation>(operation: O)` and then inside of it switch over `operationType` and do stuff with the operation related to such value.

Comment: @valeCocoa you're referring to signatures in the `Apollo` codebase, not my code. I have no control over those signatures.

Comment: @DanielKaplan then I don’t see a viable way to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps in someway:

```
class GraphQLQueryHelper
{
    static let shared = GraphQLQueryHelper()

    class func performGraphQLQuery<T:GraphQLQuery>(query: T, completion:@escaping(GraphQLSelectionSet) -> ())
    {
        Network.shared.apollo().fetch(query: query, cachePolicy: .default) { (result) in
        
            switch result
            {
            case .success(let res):
                if let data = res.data
                {
                    completion(data)
                }
                else if let error = res.errors?.first
                {
                    if let dict = error["extensions"] as? NSDictionary
                    {
                        switch dict.value(forKey: "code") as? String ?? "" {
                        case "invalid-jwt": /*Handle Refresh Token Expired*/
                        default: /*Handle error*/
                            break
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        /*Handle error*/
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    /*Handle Network error*/
                }
                break
            case .failure(let error):
                /*Handle Network error*/
                break
            }
        }
    }
    
    class func peroformGraphQLMutation<T:GraphQLMutation>(mutation: T, completion:@escaping(GraphQLSelectionSet) -> ())
    {
        Network.shared.apollo().perform(mutation: mutation) { (result) in
            switch result
            {
            case .success(let res):
                if let data = res.data
                {
                    completion(data)
                }
                else if let error = res.errors?.first
                {
                    if let dict = error["extensions"] as? NSDictionary
                    {
                        switch dict.value(forKey: "code") as? String ?? "" {
                        case "invalid-jwt": /*Handle Refresh Token Expired*/
                        default: /*Handle error*/
                            break
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        /*Handle error*/
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                   /*Handle Network error*/
                }
                break
            case .failure(let error):
                /*Handle error*/
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! An explanation as to why this would help would make it easier to tell if it's helpful.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66194191/swift-generics-protocols-can-only-be-used-as-a-generic-constraint-problem